# How to see what script is currently running during building?

Tags: ios, xcode

How to see what script is currently running during building? Console.app and Xcode debug console do not show that. Here's a progress indicator line shown in Xcode:

[image]

Comment: How about add `echo $SCRIPT_NAME` in script file? Will it appear in console?

Comment: @folex also a echo "...Script just ended". Hmmm I didn't know there was a variable SCRIPT_NAME - are you saying this is just a placeholder? In any case I usually add a "echo Starting Foo..." at the start and a "echo ... finished foo" (well, I tend to use a lot of intermediary echoes too :-))

Comment: Well, it was just a placeholder. You can use $0 -- it's scipt name (e.g. "./my_script.sh") somehow like that: `echo \`basename $0\` started`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see which script is running, and its output, in the Log navigator:

[image: log]

You can get there by clicking the speech bubble icon you see selected above, or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>.  If you print anything from your script, it will show up there as well, so you can print status messages within your script as well.